# How to get change event after js changes a value without modifing existing code

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

an input field changes its value via jquery (not by a human action), like this:
`$("#code").val(9);` .
How can I intercept the change event (or similar) without changing or add new lines to code that changes its value.

Comment: Please add your code example or clarify further.

Comment: My code is one line, this: $("#code").val(9);

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically setting value does not trigger any user events so you must trigger one yourself after the new value is set.

I used a change event but you could use others like the "input" event

```js
$("#code").on('change', function(){
  console.log('changed value =', this.value);
});


$("#code").val(9).change(); 
// or
// $("#code").val(9).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="code"/>
```

Comment: As clarified in my question I cannot change the original code, so I cannot use $("# code").val(9).change();

Comment: Well then you won't be able to listen for any changes . There are no workarounds